# Creating a new function that takes default arguments for another function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I am currently trying to create a defaultArguments function that takes in a function and some parameters that are set as default values. The steps I am thinking about taking to solve this particular problem is to:

1. Parse through the function in order to obtain what its arguments which could be anything.
2. Go through each argument that was extracted and replace arguments that have input parameters to its respective value.

Now, what I was thinking about doing next was to add additional default arguments into the input 'func'. I tried to:

1. Look up how to input a string as an argument into an existing function. However, the function then just reads the argument string as just a string.
2. Use the JavaScript .apply method. However, I won't always have all input values.

Here is the code I wrote so far.

```
function defaultArguments(func, params) {
  var reg = /\(([\s\S]*?)\)/;
  var extractVar = reg.exec(func);
  if (extractVar) {
    var arguments = extractVar[1].split(',');
  }

  for (i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (params[arguments[i]]) {
        arguments[i] = params[arguments[i]];
    }
  }
}
```

So for example, if I have a function

```
function add(a,b) { return a+b; };
```

I would use the defaultArguments function as such

```
var add_ = defaultArguments(add,{b:9});
console.log(add_(10) === 19); // b is defaulted to 9
console.log(add_(10,7) === 17); // b is given so use given value
console.log(add_()); // NaN
```

I would love some hints as to how to solve this problem and a different approach if I am approaching this problem incorrectly. I appreciate your time for reading this and I hope to see your response!

UPDATE:

So I was able to come up with a rough solution for this question. I was wondering if I approached the problem correctly and if there's any improvements do to my code. After researching a lot, I know that I shouldn't use eval(), but I don't know how else to tackle the problem. I am open to suggestions. Thanks in advance!

```
function defaultArguments(func, params) {
var stringed = func.toString();
var inputs = stringed.match(/\(.+\)/)[0].replace("(", "").replace(")", "").split(",")

for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i] = ""+inputs[i]+" = "+inputs[i]+" || "+params[inputs[i]]+";"
}

for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i ++) {
    stringed = stringed.replace("{", "{ "+inputs[i]+"")
}

var newFunc = "var restoreFunc = " + stringed;
eval(newFunc);

return restoreFunc;
}
```

Comment: _“Parse through the function in order to obtain what its arguments”_ – by that you mean parsing the actual function _code_? That will be quite complex, and also very fragile. Beside, what actual use case is there for this?

Comment: There is no actual use case for this. This is just for practice.

That statement refers to the use of regex in order to obtain the inputs for the function.